# How to typedef template function pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, function-pointers, typedef

I want to typedef a *function pointer* that points to a template function.

```
class A
{
    template <typename T>
    typedef void (*FPTR)<T>();
}
```

I have tried in this way and didn't succeed. Any idea about this thing?

Comment: Can you make an example demonstrating how you want to use said typedef?

Comment: If neither parameters types nor return type of your template function depend on template parameters, then you can use a regular function pointer (`typedef void (*FPTR)();`, or even better: `using FPTR = void (*)();`). But that pointer can only point to a specific *instantination* of the function (e.g. `FPTR ptr = foo<int>;`). It's not possible to make a function pointer point to the function template itself, rather than one of if its instantinations.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat suppose I wrote down `using FPTR = void (*)();`. Can I refer my FPTR to any initialization of foo function? Let's say I have function that has different implementations for each kind of int types like
`foo<int8>() {...}` `foo<int16>() {...}` `foo<int32>() {...}`. Can I refer my pointer to these function implementations?

Comment: As I said, if neither parameters types nor return type of your template function depend on the template parameter, then you can use a function pointer. It's not clear from your comment if that's the case or not.

Comment: Ok thank you. Yea it is. There's no return type or arguments depending on template parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @HolyBlackCat pointed out, the normal function pointer should work as you have a simple templated void function, whose template parameter does not act on both return and argument types.

```
template <typename T>
void someVoidFunction() {}

using fPtrType = void(*)();

int main()
{
    fPtrType funPtr1 = &someVoidFunction<int>;
    fPtrType funPtr2 = &someVoidFunction<float>;
    fPtrType funPtr3 = &someVoidFunction<std::string>;
    return 0;
}
```

If it was the case, that template parameters depends on the function arg and return types you should have instantiated the function pointer as well for each kind.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T someFunction(U u) {}

template <typename T, typename U>
using fPtrType = T(*)(U);

int main()
{
    fPtrType<int, float> funPtr1 = &someFunction<int, float>;  // instance 1
    fPtrType<float, float> funPtr2 = &someFunction<float, float>; // instance 2
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it is not really need to indicate the type explicitly when get the address of the function. I can use this `fPtrType<int, float> funPtr1 = &someFunction;`

Answer (score 4):

Template functions produce functions.  Template classes produce classes.  Template variables produce variables.

Pointers can point at functions or variables.  They cannot point at templates; templates have no address.

Typedef defines the type of a variable.

A template variable pointer could collectively point at various instances of a template function, but the initial binding would be done at compile time, and could only be aimed somewhere else one variable at a time.