# Function pointers to template functions

Tags: c++, function-pointers, function-templates

I have the following C++ code which compiles:

A function:

```cpp
template <typename T> T funcC(int a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Then in main, I do the following:

```cpp
int (*anythingInt)(int,double);
double (*anythingDouble)(int,double);

anythingInt = &funcC;
anythingDouble = &funcC;

std::cout << anythingInt(12, 17.5) << std::endl;
std::cout << anythingDouble(12, 17.5) << std::endl;
```

As I expected, the first cout gives 29, the second one gives 29.5. My question is - how does this work?
Does the compiler know to instantiate funcC with a double return type because anythingDouble uses this return type? If I do `anythingInt = &funcC<int>` and `anythingDouble = &funcC<double>`, then it yields the same behavior.

From what I read, function pointers can point to instances of template functions, not template functions themselves - like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53030633/how-to-typedef-template-function-pointer).

I am not doing anything of it, so how does it work, and is it legitimate code?

Comment: First things first, instead of saying "template functions" the correct term is "function template"

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @JasonLiam *The C++ Programming Language 4th edition*, 23.2.1 Defining a Template:

There are people who make semantic distinctions between the terms class template and template class. I don't; that would be too subtle: please consider those terms interchangeable. Similarly, I consider the function template interchangeable with the template function.

Comment: @RohanBari Yes, some authors use the term "template function" interchangeably with "function template". And some authors don't. I too don't think they are interchangeable at all.

Comment: @RohanBari From [FAQ](https://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#phrase-order): *"The term "function template" refers to a kind of template. The term "template function" is sometimes used to mean the same thing, and sometimes to mean a function instantiated from a function template. This ambiguity is best avoided by using "function template" for the former and something like "function template instance" or "instance of a function template" for the latter."*

Answer (score 3):

> how does it work and is it legitimate code?

When we initialize or assign a function pointer from a function
template, the compiler **uses the type of the pointer to deduce the template argument(s)**.

For example, say we have a function pointer that points to a function returning an `int` and having 2 parameters with first parameter being `int` and second being `double`.

Then we can use that function pointer to *point to an **instantiation*** of `template <typename T> T funcC(int a, double b){}`.

```
template <typename T> T funcC(int a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}
int (*ptrC)(int, double) = funcC; //ptrC point to an instantiation of funcC
```

In the above code `T` is **deduced** to be `int`(from the return type of the *function type* in the function pointer). Then `ptrC` points to a function instantiated(`template<> int funcC<int>(int a, double b)`) from the function template.

##### Example 2

On the other hand if you were to write:

```
double (*anythingDouble)(int,double) = funcC; //anythingDouble points to template<> double funcC<double>(int a, double b)
```

then `T` will be **deduced** to be `double`. Then `anythingDouble` points to a function instantiated(`template<> double funcC<double>(int a, double b)`) from the function template.